# Which of these magnets should have the strongest strength at 10cm?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

Basically, I need to generate the strongest possible field at 10 cm from a circular magnet, in its central axis.
I hesitate about what buying.

For example, the following magnet has a large diameter of 90mm and is flat, with a suction of 250 kg.

[image: large_flat]

This other magnet has a smaller diameter of 60mm, but is thicker (40 mm) with a suction of 250 kg too.

[image: thick_magnet]

This last magnet has dimension somewhere between the two others (diam = 75mm), but it is advertised to have an incredible suction of 800 kg (which I suspect to be wrong, as AliExpress is not the most reliable place should I say).

[image: very_strong]

My question is: what is best suitable for a B-field at 10 cm: a large diameter flat magnet, a not so large diameter thick magnet, or simply the strongest possible suction magnet (of course, in general, the more the suction, the more the B-field, but there may be a trade-off with the other parameters).

Also, the two first magnets are single sided (the shield on the other side leads the B-field lines directly to the first side) in order to increase the suction. But I'm not sure this increases the B-field at 10 cm far; in fact, this may well be the contrary. So, my second question is: is a shielded single side magnet stronger than the same magnet without shield, at some distance from the magnet?